# RDP not working after restart

Tags: windows, rdp

Windows Server 2022, this host is used for VPN and RDP. It works fine until when we restart it. RDP stops working. VPN, SSH, git and command line works, but not RDP.

A workaround we found is to logon in the server itself as admin and it works again. However, I do not have access to the server, and the person with administrator access is not always available.

Does anyone know why this happens and if it possible to make it work again without a physical presence to logon?

I tried restarting the services related to RDP with PowerShell but it did not work.  The services are running but I cannot connect.

I also read somethings about NIC. I am not sure what that is, network interfaces? If so, then it should not be a problem since we only have one. I also saw that some people had the issue when restarting from RDP but we did no do that, we restart it from the PC itself.Finally i tried restarting again through SSH but also did not work.

Comment: Can you check if the rdp port is listening? `netstat -an | find "3389"` from an administrator command prompt  https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That port is not listening but the one we use for RDP does, `TCP    0.0.0.0:XXXX           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING`